# Client-side Microsoft Word to PDF conversion - how to in MVC3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, pdf-generation

I have a file upload control on my page. When a user selects a .DOC/DOCX file in the control, I need to show the selected file on the page but in PDF format.

I can show the PDF using embed tag as usual, but what should be the sequence be that I need to follow here?

I am using ASP.NET MVC3.  Can I perform this using javacript?

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to upload a .doc/.docx, convert it to pdf, then show the user the pdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting a DOCX file to PDF using javascript might be a little tough and a territory I wouldn't venture into. So once the file is being uploaded on the server you could use some standard library that will perform the conversion. There are some libraries such as [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial but very reliable) or [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) (free) which will allow you to do this. Once the file is converted into a PDF you could store it on the server and return its location so that the client can build an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag dynamically pointing to it and show it inline as a preview.